# Creating a sliding segue in Swift

Tags: swift, segue, catransition

I am trying to create a segue/transition between two View Controllers that "slides" to the next View Controller. What I mean by "slide" is that it only moves as much as the translation of a pan gesture(similar to Snapchat). If you could help me with this or just point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That effect is achieved using custom interactive transitions, which were introduced in iOS7. Here are a few tutorials to check out:

- See *Custom Transitions Using View Controllers*. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/
- http://www.thinkandbuild.it/ios7-custom-transitions/
- http://objectivetoast.com/2014/04/14/interactive-transitions/
- http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/
- This one gives many examples of the effects that can be achieved. http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/

---

When I was implementing this I found that, for reusability, it was best to have one subclass of `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` (which we'll call `TransitionManager`) that implemented the protocols `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

**-** Then, if you need to present a `UIViewController` modally with your custom transition: in `prepareForSegue` set:

```
destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate  = TransitionManager()
```

**-** If you're using a `UINavigationController` it's even easier, all you need to do it set the `UINavigationController`'s `delegate` to your `TransitionManager`.

Hopefully that should start to make some sense once you've gone through the tutorials.